# Order By in the query makes it slower

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table schema like follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_name` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '101',
  `column1` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'aaa',
  `column2` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '0=a 1=b 2=c 3=d 5=e 6=f-f 7=g-g',
  `vergrund` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '103',
  `column2` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '108',
  `land` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '109',
  `column2` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '110',
  `marke` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '111',
  `modell` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '112',
  `market` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '125',
  `picture_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `update_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `marke` (`marke`),
  KEY `modell` (`marke`,`modell`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

This table have data of around 500K. I am trying simple query as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT marke, 
                modell, 
                column1, 
                column2, 
                column3, 
                column4, 
                land, 
                column5, 
                plattform, 
                id 
FROM   tbl_name 
WHERE  vergrund IN ( "...." ) 
       AND picture_status >= 1 
       AND update_status = 0 
ORDER  BY marke, 
          modell
```

When I run this query without order by it takes around 8 second. But when I add order by, it is taking long time of around 25 second. I have marke and modell as key too.

Can anybody help me how can I fast this query.

Comment: You're asking it to do more, which takes more time. Part of it is also likely the distinct. Creating an index on those columns may help reduce some of the added time.

Comment: Run the query with `EXPLAIN` to see where all the time is being used.

Comment: vergrund ? I don't see that in the table?

Comment: @babno There's an index on `(marke, modell)`, the columns in the `ORDER BY`. Theoretically that should mean the ordering should not slow down the query. It still has to scan everything for the `WHERE` clause, since none of those columns are indexed. But that's the same with and without ordering.

Comment: One of the column is vergrund @P.Salmon

Comment: @cOle2 when run with EXPLAIN I get extra `Using where; Using filesort` possible_keys: NULL, key: NULL, key_len:null, ref:null

Comment: Why possible keys is showing null ?

Comment: Did you try building an index around the columns which appear in the WHERE?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the primary key, so `select distinct` is not necessary.  This should help:

```
SELECT marke, modell, column1, column2, column3, column4, 
       land, column5, plattform, id 
FROM  tbl_name 
WHERE vergrund IN ( "...." ) AND
      picture_status >= 1 AND
      update_status = 0 
ORDER BY marke, modell ;
```

I don't know if MySQL is smart enough to use the index for sorting, but this should help a bit.

Comment: it reduces 1 second. But still its slow